# DLL doesn't work when removed from its original location

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll

I'm writing an application in VB.NET, and one of its requirements is to interface with a piece of hardware for making optical power measurements.The company that produced the hardware has DLLs on the machine (which is running either Windows 2000 or XP, depending on which one I look at), and we currently have software which works with those DLLs and is written in VB6.

In addition to interfacing with these machines, the application I am writing also will need to interface with other machines that take measurements using hardware produced by different companies and that uses different calls. Since I don't know that the DLLs will always be there, I decided that I would include them in the program.

I checked in the VB6 project what references were being utilized, and based on those, I transferred the necessary DLLs into the project, loaded them as references, and the project compiled. But it didn't run. I've tried copying or not copying the DLLs, putting them in the same path on the computer I'm using to write the application. Everything I do seems to result in an error that reads:

> Could not load file or assembly Interop.Instrument12001b, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, Public Key Token = null or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

At this point, I'm not exactly sure what options I have left. I could try loading the DLLs at run-time, but 1) will I be able to ignore the errors to compile the program? and 2) will that work even though I don't know the contents of the DLLs?

EDIT:
As it turns out, the entire problems was due to a bug in VS2013 Express. For whatever reason, that particular version of Visual Studio will not create Interop DLLs for .NET 2.0. I was able to get around this by using VS2010 Express instead.

Comment: You can troubleshoot issues like this using the [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

When you reference a COM library, VS generates an Interop DLL, which is a .NET assembly that allows your .NET application to interoperate with the COM library.  When you deploy, the Interop library must be in the same folder as your EXE but you still need the COM library present and registered on the target machine, otherwise there's nothing to interoperate with.

Comment: When you say "registered", do you simply mean present in the same location it was on the original machine, or is there something more I have to do to get the library to register?

Do I also need to bring my Interop DLLs with the program? Are they not included in the EXE file?

Comment: If the DLL was "included" in the EXE then I wouldn't have said "the Interop library must be in the same folder as your EXE".  As for registering, that's how COM works.  One of the great things about .NET is that you can simply put an assembly on a machine and it will work.  With COM components, you have to register them with the system, so the system knows what they are and where they are.  If a COM component isn't registered then the system doesn't know it exists so no application can use it.  If you want to know more about registering COM components, a web search would be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. The good news is after putting those Interop libraries where they belong, I'm no longer getting the error saying that the system can't find the specified file. The bad news is that I'm getting an error that says "the assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded", which is perplexing as I'm compiling in .NET 2.0 and running in .NET 2.0.

Comment: Update: It looks like the issue is probably due to the tlbimp.exe using .NET 4.5 to convert the COM files, so I'm looking into that now.